# Display original value in JSF f:convertNumber (unlimited number of fraction digits)

Tags: jsf-2.2, omnifaces, jsf-2.3

I'm using a `<f:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" />` within my `<h:inputText` to convert the users input to a number. When opening the input dialog again, the input is formatted to show only 3 fraction digits. How can I change this to show the input "as it is".

To format the value in output I'm using `#{of:formatNumber(specification.pricePerUnit, '#0.000')}` to display 3 fraction digits (at least). Unfortunately we have customers, which would like to enter more fraction digits (problem above). So, how could I display the number with at least 3 fraction digits, but if there are more, show them all?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem well - just use `'#.000#######'` format to always display 3 fraction digits (even if they are 0), and up to 10 fraction digits whey there are not 0. For examle this: `<h:outputText value="#{of:formatNumber(123.123456789012345, '#.000#######')}" />` will display :`123,123456789` and this one: `<h:outputText value="#{of:formatNumber(123.4, '#.000#######')}" />` will display: `123,400`

Comment: ah okay, thanks. This is working fine for displaying the value. :)
The other problem is about editing that value, e.g. for the value `123,123456789` the h:input is displaying `123,123` instead the 'real' value.

Comment: okay, there is this attribute `maxFractionDigits`, which I could also set to `10`. But isn't there a way to display the value in `h:input` as it comes from database, but as localized number?

Comment: I don't understand you question: `But isn't there a way to display the value in h:input as it comes from database, but as localized number?` - yes, it is, this is what converters are supposed to do. Mayby it would be better if you showed your actual code (only a part which is not working as expected), or even better created a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: okay, let's suppose the following: I have a form with: `<h:inputText id="..." value="..."><f:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" /></h:inputText>`. I enter the value `123,123456789` and save it. WIth your code above on another page the value is displayed as `123,123456789`. But when I open the form again to edit the value, the input field displays it as `123,123` but not `123,123456789`. So, I assume that the default value for `maxFractionDigits` is 3?

Comment: @jheider "So, I assume that the default value for maxFractionDigits is 3?" Rarely documented, but exactly my observation, too. I am on org.glassfish/javax.faces 2.3.9

Answer (score 1):

> okay, let's suppose the following: I have a form with: . I enter the value 123,123456789 and save it. WIth
>   your code above on another page the value is displayed as
>   123,123456789. But when I open the form again to edit the value, the
>   input field displays it as 123,123 but not 123,123456789. So, I assume
>   that the default value for maxFractionDigits is 3?

A very basic example:

```
<h:form>
    <div>
    <h:outputText value="#{of:formatNumber( testBean.myNumber, '0.000#######')}" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <h:inputText value="#{testBean.myNumber}" >
        <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" pattern='0.000#######' />
    </h:inputText>
    </div>
    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit" />
</h:form>
```

and a bean code:

```
private BigDecimal myNumber = new  BigDecimal("355.3456");

public BigDecimal getMyNumber() {
    return myNumber;
}

public void setMyNumber(BigDecimal myNumber) {
    this.myNumber = myNumber;
}
```

---

A few tests:
A page looks like below after a first GET request:

[image]

---

Now I type in 12345.6789099

[image]

---

And after the `Submit` button has been clicked:
[image]

---

A few another examples:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ah okay, so I have to add this pattern everywhere. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to find any documentation, but in *org.glassfish/javax.faces 2.3.9* I obverse, too, that there is a default-value of **3** for maxFractionDigits.

```
<f:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" />
```

equals

```
<f:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" maxFractionDigits="3" />
```

change it to your needs:

```
<f:convertNumber groupingUsed="false" maxFractionDigits="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To let the user enter a double with many digits, you have to use `h:inputText` without converter.

If you want to display it nicely (readonly) you can use `f:convertNumber` but you need the scale to find the number of digits (convert your Double to a BigDecimal for example).

To display it in a dataTable, you can use Omnifaces converter
https://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/converter